# compare all elements in a list haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion, compare

I have a list with elements that are tuples example:

`[(1,2),(3,9),(7,9),(6,4),(1,2),(4,2),(3,9),(1,2)]`

I need to compare the first element with the rest of the elements, then then the second item with the rest of the list and so on to return the repeated elements

In this case it should return

`(1,2),(1,2),(1,2),(3,9),(3,9)`

any idea how to implement it?

I have this implemented

```
test :: Eq a => [(a,a)] -> [(a,a)]
test [(x,y)] = [(x,y)]
test (x:y:xs) 
    |((fst (x) == fst (y)) && (snd (x) == snd (y))) = ( [y]) ++ (test (x:xs) )
    |otherwise = test (x:xs)
```

the end condition is bad and always returns the last element of the list
`test [(x,y)] = [(x,y)]`

And it only compares the first item with the rest of the list but I need to compare the second, the third ... with the rest of the list

Comment: Hint: `import Data.List (partition); test (x:xs) = _ where (ys,zs) = partition _ _`

Comment: Why is this restricted to pairs? Can't you write `test :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]` and just call that with a list of pairs? You're making life harder on yourself while making your function less useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first of all if you have two tuples, comparing element wise is the same as using `==`. So

```hs
-- This code
(fst (x) == fst (y)) && (snd (x) == snd (y))
-- is the same as this code
x == y
```

Second, notice the **recursive** nature of your function. Let say you have a way to split your current list into

- `ys` the list of elements equal to the first one
- `zs` the list of elements not equal to the first one

Then `ys` will be the first part of your final solution. What do you need to do with `zs` to get the rest of the solution?

Below, theres is a litle guide line you can fill. (this is obviously an assigment, so I'm not going to give you the full answer)

```hs
-- if you can't use imports, defined yourself this function.
import Data.List (partition)

test :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
test [] = []
-- Hint: use recursion
test (x:xs) = undefined -- Notice that if ys is empty, then x wouldn't be a repeated element, so it should be discarted. 
 where (ys, zs) = partition (== x) xs
--      |   |- This is the list of element not equals to x
--      |- This is the list of elements equals to x
```

Comment: I upvoted because this answer gives good learning advice and helps the OP reason about their code and improve it. However it should be noted that this algorithm has quadratic time complexity. It is possible to solve this problem with pseudo-linear time complexity, either by calculating all the frequencies and storing them in a Map, or by sorting the list so that duplicate elements are adjacent.